# Where can I found a documentation for raw input of LLDB commands?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, lldb

Some of LLDB commands have informations that accept raw input but I am not sure what can be in that 'input'. It seems to me that it is not specified by documentation.
For example:

`process launch --stop-at-entry -- -program_arg value`

I really don't know what -program_arg is, why it is here and if there can be other parameters in the raw input section.

What help process launch returns:

```
Launch the executable in the debugger.
Syntax: process launch <cmd-options> [<run-args>]

Command Options Usage:
...

This command takes options and free-form arguments.  If your arguments
resemble option specifiers (i.e., they start with a - or --), you must use
' -- ' between the end of the command options and the beginning of the
arguments.
```

What help  returns:

```
  <run-args> -- Arguments to be passed to the target program when it starts
                executing.
```

These documentation aren't helpful for me. Does anyone know if there is any place where I can find the raw input specifications for built LLDB commands?

Comment: A quick search on google for `lldb documentation` comes up with plenty of links. I'd suggest starting with https://lldb.llvm.org

Answer (score 0):

So we have to be able to specify arguments to your program that might look like arguments to the current "process launch" commands. Since run-args could be anything, the LLDB command line parser needs to know what options are for the "process launch" commands and which ones are for the process you are about to launch. For example if our "a.out" program actually has a "--stop-at-entry" option, and you want to specify it for your program, and if you type:

```
(lldb) process launch --stop-at-entry
```

LLDB is going to parse the "--stop-at-entry" as an option for the "process launch" command and not consider it an argument for your program. If you want "--stop-at-entry" to be an argument for your program and not for the "process launch" command your command, you need to terminate the "process launch" options with "--" and then anything that comes after that will be passed to the process, and this is wha is referred to as free-form arguments:

```
(lldb) process launch -- --stop-at-entry
```

You can even specify --stop-at-entry for both your program *and* for the "process launch" command with:

```
(lldb) process launch --stop-at-entry -- --stop-at-entry
```

But if you have arguments that don't start with - or --, you don't need the "--":

```
(lldb) process launch --stop-at-entry arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This will have --stop-at-entry be an option for "process launch" and the free form arguments are "arg1 arg2 arg3". Most of the time the arguments you pass to your program will not be the same as the ones for process launch so if you did this:

```
(lldb) process launch --program-arg1 --program-arg2 --address 0x1000
```

Since we didn't use "--" before --program-arg1, "process launch" will think any options are meant for the "process launch" command and you will get an error:

```
(lldb) process launch --program-arg1 --program-arg2 --address 0x1000
error: unknown or ambiguous option
```

So fix this by using the "--":

```
(lldb) process launch -- --program-arg1 --program-arg2 --address 0x1000
```